# How do I host an app created with Polymer?

Tags: heroku, polymer, web-hosting, host

I've been Googling this problem for some weeks now and can't find a solution to what seems to be a simple problem. It seems to get pretty convoluted pretty quickly.

I've read through the node.js Heroku getting started and a lot of other tutorials but it seems to be that it won't work with Polymer. I can see my app looks and works fine when I run `python -m http.server 8000` from the command line in my directory I can view my app in the localhost and it looks great!

If anyone has any clue as to where I should go from here or can point me to any useful links that would be amazing! Even better if there is some kind of skeleton Polymer website that is freely available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't trying to host a node.js or other backend with your polymer app you can use github pages. https://pages.github.com/

Polymer app is essentially only files that the browser needs to retrieve from remote server. You don't need to have backend on the host server. If you were trying to host node.js or other backend you could use heroku to host it.

Comment: When you say 'host a node.js' do you mean I can't have any JavaScript files at all with my polymer app if I use github? Because I do have a node file which handles all the logic from the html.

Comment: You can have javascript files with your polymer app on github. What I mean is that you can't have a node.js server from which you are retrieving information. If you are making calls to a node.js server (e.g. express) you can't host that. Github pages can host files that the user needs to view your website. AS it sounds github pages can be used in your case.

Comment: Here is the Polymer Web Start kit hosted on a github site: http://jptrainor.github.io/polymer-starter-kit/dist/#!/polymer-starter-kit/dist/ Here is the repo: https://github.com/jptrainor/jptrainor.github.io. It is no different that any other web site. In the case of the starter kit just build and publish the dist directory.